# What is the correct field to pass --staging-location parameter for a Dataflow job in Node.js?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-apis-explorer

I wonder if I've hit a bug. A wrote a Node.js piece of code to trigger a "GCS Text to PubSub" Dataflow. The function is triggered upon file upload into a GCS bucket.
But it never executes successfully: "textPayload:  "problem running dataflow template, error was:  { Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "staging_location": Cannot find field." It is an issue with the syntax of I specify the staging location for the job. I have tried "staginglocation", "stagingLocation", etc...none of them have worked.

Here's my code. Thanks for your help.

```js
var {google} = require('googleapis');

exports.moveDataFromGCStoPubSub = (event, callback) => {


const file = event.data;
const context = event.context;

console.log(`Event ${context.eventId}`);
console.log(`  Event Type: ${context.eventType}`);
console.log(`  Bucket: ${file.bucket}`);
console.log(`  File: ${file.name}`);
console.log(`  Metageneration: ${file.metageneration}`);
console.log(`  Created: ${file.timeCreated}`);
console.log(`  Updated: ${file.updated}`);

  google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }

 console.log(projectId);

 const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: 'v1b3', auth: authClient });
 console.log(`gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`);
 dataflow.projects.templates.create({
   projectId: projectId,
   resource: {
    parameters: {
        inputFile: `gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`,
        outputTopic: `projects/iot-fitness-198120/topics/MemberFitnessData`,
      },
      jobName: 'CStoPubSub',
      gcsPath: 'gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub',
      stagingLocation: 'gs://fitnessanalytics-tmp/tmp'    
    }
 }, function(err, response) {
   if (err) {
     console.error("problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
   }
   console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
   callback();
 });

   });

 callback();
};
```

Comment: Additionnal information: it seems everytime I pass this parameter, no matter whether I wrote staginglocation, stagingLocation or else, the system interpretes it as staging_location and is not happy with this field name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is actually possible.

Looking at [the documentation for the Dataflow API itself](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.templates/create), there's nothing like a staging location in the parameter section, and the library you're using is basically a wrapper for this API.

I'm a bit surprised it changes the name of the parameter though.

Comment: I got it to work finally. It was indeed a syntax problem. Since I am still new to stackoverflow: shall I share my code here for the "community" ? Happy to do that if that's how it works over here.

Comment: Yes, please do. Post it as an answer to your own question, with the code that works. Anyone else that runs into the same issue will then be able to find the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

So i finally got this to work. It was indeed a syntax issue in the parameters section. The code below works like a charm:

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');

exports.moveDataFromGCStoPubSub = (event, callback) => {


const file = event.data;
const context = event.context;

console.log(`Event ${context.eventId}`);
console.log(`  Event Type: ${context.eventType}`);
console.log(`  Bucket: ${file.bucket}`);
console.log(`  File: ${file.name}`);
console.log(`  Metageneration: ${file.metageneration}`);
console.log(`  Created: ${file.timeCreated}`);
console.log(`  Updated: ${file.updated}`);

  google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }

 console.log(projectId);

 const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: 'v1b3', auth: authClient });
 console.log(`gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`);
 dataflow.projects.templates.create({
  gcsPath: 'gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub', 
  projectId: projectId,
   resource: {
    parameters: {
        inputFilePattern: `gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`,
        outputTopic: 'projects/iot-fitness-198120/topics/MemberFitnessData2'
      },
    environment: {
      tempLocation: 'gs://fitnessanalytics-tmp/tmp'
    },
      jobName: 'CStoPubSub',
      //gcsPath: 'gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub',    
    }
 }, function(err, response) {
   if (err) {
     console.error("problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
   }
   console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
   callback();
 });

   });

 callback();
};
```